# Positioning an SVG element using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am doing a modification on svg-edit. I am using a function to make a path element bigger or smaller based on width and height inputs by the user. The user selects an element and clicks on a button to fire up the function which takes the last known width and heght measurements and then asks from the user the new width and height values. It then creates a divisor which it uses to create a TRANSFORM MATRIX operation on the element to make it as big as the user wants.

The problem is that when transforming matrices, the elements also changes position.

I want when the user is asked for a width and height also to be asked for x,y position on canvas and then move the selected element to that position.

Is their a way of repositioning an svg element?

```
   function changeDimensions() 

    {
  svgNode = svgCanvas.getSelectedElems()[0];

var dims = Raphael.pathBBox(svgNode.getAttribute('d')); 
lasth = parseInt(dims.height); 
lastw= parseInt(dims.width);

var transformw=prompt("Enter your new width");
var transformh=prompt("Enter your new height");
newW=transformw/lastw;
 newH=transformh/lasth;
```

svgCanvas.changeSelectedAttribute("transform", "matrix(" + newW + ", 0, 0, " + newH + ", 0, 0)");
svgCanvas.recalculateAllSelectedDimensions();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different svg elements have different attributes that they use to position themselves. For example rect's have x and y attributes but circles have cx, and cy. Path's do not have separate attributes.

However you can probably get what you need from a transform! Most svg elements will accept a [transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute where you can assign a translation. E.g.

```
<path d="M10,10L20,100" transform="translate(30,40)"/>
```

In fact you can probably scale your path with the same transform attribute.

Comment: any idea how can this be done using a javascript command? For instance lets say my pathsiD is svg_1. What JS code would move my svg_1 to position say 30,50?

Comment: Okkay i just used this:    svg_1.setAttribute('transform','translate(-30,50)');     Only thing is that this just moves my element 30pixels left and 50 pixels down than it already was instead of sending the element to position 30,50. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends a bit on what you mean by position? Relative to which? Probably your best bet is to use something like jQuery's [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) functions on your path to figure out the correct translation to apply. [d3](http://d3js.org/) has similar functions and a lot of ways to work with svg also.

Comment: Your "dims" var should include the current offset, so you can use this to compute the relative translation. Of course you might want to use your initial bounding box x,y so that the user can set the position more than once. I would think my final transform attribute would look something like: tranform="translate(-orig_x,-orig_y)scale(newW,newH)translate(final_x,final_y)" I don't know if you can set up a jsFiddle with Raphael but if you did we could try to play with it. I know svg but though I've heard about it I have not yet used Raphael :)

Comment: you can use the matrix or scale or a combination. I find it easier to know what is going on with a sequence of transforms rather that computing the whole matrix myself. To create a fiddle you just need to go to http://jsfiddle.net/ I think raphael is available as one of the "frameworks" but you may need to add other libraries under "Add Resources" Also you can go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zXd2J/) and select "fork" from the toolbar on top. You do not need an account. Make your changes, save/update it and post the link.